# MenuItemCallback, visual studio package and createa new file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am writing `visual studio package`, My requirement is that user must created `empty visual studio project C++ or C#`. How Do i get access to this project in `private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)` so that I can add some dynamically generated files to it.

This is what I have done till now

```
private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        IVsSolution solutionService = GetService(typeof(SVsSolution)) as IVsSolution;
        // get all projects in solution
         IEnumHierarchies enumHierarchies = null;
         Guid guid = Guid.Empty;
                ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(solutionService.GetProjectEnum(     (uint)__VSENUMPROJFLAGS.EPF_ALLINSOLUTION,ref guid,out enumHierarchies));
                //Loop all projects found
                if (enumHierarchies != null)
                {
                    // Loop projects found
                    IVsHierarchy[] hierarchy = new IVsHierarchy[1];
                    uint fetched = 0;

                    while (enumHierarchies.Next(1, hierarchy, out fetched) == VSConstants.S_OK && fetched == 1)                {                   
                        Guid projectGuid;
                        ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(hierarchy[0].GetGuidProperty(VSConstants.VSITEMID_ROOT, (int)__VSHPROPID.VSHPROPID_ProjectIDGuid, out projectGuid));
                    }
                }            
            }
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create a template of a project, i.e. a kind of project that the users can choose from, like when you choose between a Class Library, a Console Application, a Windows Form Application, and so on? Or do you have some reason to develop an AddIn that add the files whenever a user creates a new Empty Project?

Comment: I have created a new Menu Item which generate wizards and ask some question based on the response I want to generate some header and code files.

Comment: OK. It is possible to use this wizard to drive the output of a project template. Is this what you want to do or do you want to act on every empty project which is created?

Comment: I have certain SDK and I want user to create empty project either Shared DLL or executable type, then ask some question and based on the response add some files which has automated code , which will take care of initialization of SDK and all that

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Shared DLL project and an executable project, then add all the needed references and the files with your needed initialization code. You can't export your projects as a template yet, since you need to take care of the users' directions.

If you have some particular strings that depend upon the input of the user or the name of the project, you have to identify them as parameters by putting their name between $ (there are even some standard parameters for templates). For instance you could have something like:

```
public class $aclassname$ : YourBaseClass
```

To use your wizard to have the user you have to create another project with a class that implements Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard.IWizard, in particular this method:

```
public void RunStarted(object automationObject, Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary, WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams)
```

Inside this method you can open your own wizard, and then act according to the input from the user. In particular you can add items to the replacementsDictionary to replace the parameters you put in your template, for instance:

```
replacementsDictionary.Add("$aclassname$", aVarFromYourWizard);
```

Furthermore, automationobject is an instance of EnvDTE.DTEClass pointing to your VisualStudio instance. This means that you can cast it to DTEClass and then use it to get the project you are creating and modify it according to your needs.

When you finish this wizard project, in order to use your templates you have first of all to sign this wizard assembly, then you can go back tou your template projects to export them (File -> Export template as VSIX) being careful to specify your Wizard Assembly.

You could also take look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx) and [here](http://windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/windows/2006/10/17/creating-visual-studio-project-templates.html?page=2).

EDIT:

I forgot to add that IWizard has a mathod that allows you to specify whether a file in your template has to be added to your actual project or not. You can obviously use the data from your wizard to decide what to do. It is:

```
public bool ShouldAddProjectItem(string filePath)
```

I think that this way is much easier and maintainable than developing an AddIn.